# How to drive 1 MHz ultrasonic transducer, transmitter-reciever schematic

Tags: circuit-design, driver, esp32, ultrasound, signal-generator

I have just bought some ultrasonic sensors from China for a project I'm developing, and the datasheet is not the best, also with my low electrical engineering skills, I am not sure of how to drive the passive piezoelectric crystal (I'm referring to the ultrasonic transducer). Could anyone give some advice on how to design a transmitter-receiver circuit for one same ultrasound sensor? Here is some data that might be useful. Also in terms of generating a 1 MHz square wave, is it possible to do on an ESP32?

This is part of the datasheet, apparently:

Advice on excitation voltages:  9-12 V，max 36 V, if could accept high power consumption, could undertake 110 V. The most suitable voltage, that user test and find signal-to-noise ratio of the received signal can meet their requirements.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this transducer - are you making a fish finder or depth meter, or communications system?

Comment: Im trying to measure water flow inside pvc pipes, also potentially metal. I was told this sensor was capable of that. So basically doing a delta tof sensor

Comment: Could you post a link to the datasheet, if any?